# Spring boot and Spring Security, different logon forms to use different success handlers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring boot/mvc site using spring security.
I have to use ways of logging in, 
In the navbar present on each page
and the login page which you are redirected to when attempting to access a restricted resource.

For the navbar i'd like the user to stay on the page after successful login
For the login page i'd like the user to be redirected to the resource they were trying to originally access after login.

I can do each functionality individually
First use case is handled by:

```
SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();

    handler.setUseReferer(true);
```

Second case is the default functionality.
But i've been unable to make them both work.

Does anyone have any insights on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure each login page with a different AuthenticationSuccessHandler like described here
https://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login

Like:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/anonymous*").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler())

                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login2.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login2")
                .successHandler(mySecondAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: So say I had my logon page "/login" and a "/home"
I wanted "/home" to use a customer success handler and "/login" to use the default functionality. I would do

```and()  
                .formLogin()  
                .loginPage("/login.html")  
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")  

                .and()  
                .formLogin()  
                .loginPage("/home")  
                .loginProcessingUrl("/home")  
                .successHandler(myCustomSuccessHandler());  
```

Because this seems that the custom success handler is used for everything